# ServiceStack - CSV column header (not per DataContract - DataMember Name=<value>)

Tags: servicestack

Created a Model class with DataContract and DataMember Name for each property in the class. The XML, JSON, JSV contents comes out with the Name as specified in the DataContract attribute. But CSV is not, it display the actual name of the property in the class.

Example header in XML, JSON, JSV:

FileNumber, AccountYear, AgreementDate, CollectionDate

Example header in CSV:

FILE_NO,ACCOUNT_YR,AGREEMENT_DATE,COLLECTION_DATE

I do not have any custom formatters / handlers for CSV, its all what comes with ServiceStack.

Is this how it is OR is any settings is required?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The CSV serializer currently doesn't look at the **Name** property of the `[DataMember]` attribute.

Although if you add [an issue on the ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/issues?direction=desc&sort=created&state=open) project, we can look at adding support for this in future.

Comment: Thanks. Will add it (with low priority) to keep them consistent.